# Amended very first commit added more commits

Tags: git

I wanted to remove a file from my very first initial commit:

```
git rebase -i --root
```

set the first commit to edit

```
git rm *filename
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Now I have a new commit that consists of the history of commits (which successfully removed the file I wanted from initial commit), but previous commits also remain.
So there are duplicate commits now. My question is how to only want to keep my most current commit.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like something is still referencing them. It may be because you have other branches, which are still pointing to some of the old commits .Run `git log --all --graph` to see what it is.

You can then reset your branches to their new, rebased commits by doing `git checkout <other_branch>`, then `git reset --hard <new_rebased_commit>`.

Once you're done, you may want to delete the old commits by running `git gc --prune=all`. If you don't do that, they can still be found, for example, by using `git reflog`

Comment: thxs for the reply, i just tried, but it doesnt seem to work. I even went ahead and deleted that extra branch. Now theres only the mast branch.

Comment: Did you push your work to a remote? Because they are shown too (e.g. as `origin/master`. Then you have to force push with `git push <remote_name> <branch_name>`.

Comment: Also, tags can reference commits too.

Comment: The references are shown in braces (e.g.

`commit <sha> (<ref_1>, <ref_2>)`

)

Comment: Can you maybe show the output of `git log --all --graph`?

Comment: can i pm you directly?